# Wait for a file to finish copying before acting on it?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple node.js application that watches a directory for new PDF files. When it sees them show up it FTPs them out and moves them to another directory.

The problem I'm running into is if the file happens to be a little large (10MB for example) my application starts processing the file before it has finished copying into the directory.

The copy is happening over the network so that can slow things down a little too. I need a way to tell my application to wait until the file has finished copying before processing it.

What would be the best way to do this? I've tried the 'growing-file' module but it just doesn't seem to work and it looks like the developer has abandoned it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Eh.  Copy the file to a temporary location on the same filesystem, then move it into the "to be processed" directory.  The file will be moved all at once on any decent OS.

Comment: How about sending the file as "xyz.inprogress" and renaming it as "xyz.pdf" after the transfer is complete?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7242053/41576 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582827/how-to-check-in-node-js-if-a-file-is-open-being-written-to

Comment: Yeah, I was really making this more complicated than it needed to be! I went with idea @MarkSetchell suggested and had the file end in '.inProgress' until it had completely transferred. That works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem, I needed to download files before playing them. I end up writing this code, which you can easily rewrite for your operation.

EDIT: In fact, you almost can use the code as-if, just be careful about the callback of download.

It make use of callback to download each files one-by-one (I had bandwith problem), but I had a previous version which started all download and then waited for all files to be on disk before callback.

You ll need to have a global variable named DOWNLOAD_DIR which contain full path to the download directory if you want to use it as-it.

You ll also need http, but I think you already have it.

```
var http = require('http');

/*download
IN_: file_url
        string
        url of the file to download
     callback
COM: Download the specified file to DOWNLOAD_DIR/name_of_the_file, and callback the full path to the file
     callback null on error.
*/
function download(file_url, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: url.parse(file_url).host,
        port: 80,
        path: url.parse(file_url).pathname
    },
        file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop(),
    //Creating the file
        file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name, {flags: 'w', encoding: 'binary'}),
    console.log('Downloading file from ' + file_url);
    console.log(LOG, '\tto ' + file_name);
    http.get(options, function (res) {
        res.pipe(file, {end: 'false'});
        //When the file is complete
        res.on('end', function () {
            //Closing the file
            file.end();
            console.log(LOG, '\t\tDownloaded '+ file_name);
            callback(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name);
        });
    });

    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
        console.log('Can t download ' + file_url + '\t(' + err + ')');
        callback(null);
    });

}

/*download_all
IN_: list
        array of string
        Names of the files to download
     callback
COM: Download all the file one after another
*/
function download_all(list, callback) {
    var i = 0, 
        fe;

    function follow() {
        //If there is download to do
        if (i < list.length) {
            //Checking if the file already exist
            fe = fs.existsSync(DOWNLOAD_DIR + list[i].substr(list[i].lastIndexOf('/')));
            console.log('Checking ' + list[i]);
            if (!fe) {
                console.log('\tDo not exist');
                //If it doesn t, downloading it
                download(list[i], function () {
                    i = i + 1;
                    //And go to the next file
                    follow();
                });
            } else {
                //If it does, go to the next file
                console.log('\tExist');
                i = i + 1;
                follow();
            }
        } else {
            //When all files are downloaded
            console.log('end');
            callback();
        }
    }
    follow();
}
```

Note that in production code, you should replace fs.existSync (in download) by fs.exist + callback

EDIT: Here the code for a fire-all-at-once download. Note that it is old code I ve edited a bit.

Note that this code is old, I didn t tested it a lot, and use fs.existSync too (which, again, is bad for production code).

Last note, if a download fail, the callback of download will have null has parameters, you will have to check that yourself.

```
/*download_all
IN_: list
        array of string
        Names of the files to download
     callback
COM: Download all-at-once
*/
function download_all(list, callback){
    var i=0, dltd, dlcp=0;
    dltd=list.length;

    function afterDownload(){
        dlcp=dlcp+1;
        console.log("Telechargement fini:"+dlcp);
        if(dlcp===dltd){
            callback();
        }
    }

    while(i<list.length)
    {
        if(!fs.existsSync(DOWNLOAD_DIR + list[i].substr(list[i].lastIndexOf('/'))))
        {
            //If the file do not exist
            download(list[i], afterDownload);
        } else {
            afterDownload();
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var http = require('http'),
    DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/home/user/download/',
    list = ['http://somewebsite.com/video.mp4', 'http://somewebsite.com/video2.mp4', 'http://othersite.com/image.png'];

download_all(list, function (){
    //Do stuff
});
```

Comment: How about if you have multiple files that need to be downloaded and check to see if they are completed before triggering a different function?

Comment: That is what it is doing. However, it is a old answer, using already old techniques. You should use flow control library like `async`, or better yet, `Promise` to do that. Do you want me to update my answer?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I actually got a similar question regarding this. 
I first download images to a folder(I don't know when they are finished) & zip the folder. Because I have multiple images I need to keep calling the download image function multiple times which create more complexity.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924340/how-to-trigger-a-function-after-all-the-downloads-are-finished

Comment: @GokhanDilek: Could you join me on the [node.js chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js)? Your problem is sync vs async. While giving you the correct code would be easy, you would not understand the concept behind and why your code failed. I heavily reccomend you read about the event loop and async programming. [Here a article about it](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)

Comment: Thanks. I am in the room now.