# How to trigger a function after all the downloads are finished

Tags: node.js

I would like to give you a background first.

I have an array of image parameters just like below:

```
    "imageParameters": [
      {
        "imageparam1": "param1",
        "imageparam2": "param2",
        "imageparam3": "param3"
      },

      {
        "imageparam1": "param1",
        "imageparam2": "param2",
        "imageparam3": "param3"
      }
    ]
```

I loop through this to generate unique urls per image.
Then trigger the downloadImageAndSave function each time url is generated.

```
imageParameters.forEach(function (image) {
var imageUrL = baseURL + "&param1=" + image.imageparam1 + "&param2=" + image.imageparam2 + "&param3=" + image.imageparam3 ;

var imageparam1 = image.imageparam1;
downloadImageAndSave(imageUrL, imageparam1);   

    });

function downloadImageAndSave(imageUrL, imageparam1) {

    console.log("Download function is triggered")
    var fs = require('fs'),
        request = require('request');

    request
        .get(imageUrL)
        .on('error', function(err) {
            // handle error
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./imagesLocation/' + imageparam1 + '.jpeg'));

myfunctionTobeTRiggeredAfterImagesDownloadedAndSaved();
}
```

How do I know all of these images are downloaded and saved so that I can trigger my function?

The problem I am having is to use the callback. I am not how I can get callback once all of the images are downloaded and saved.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

**UPDATED**

Below is the workflow I am trying to achieve.
I get an input from the user via express API like this.

```
 app.get('/getStudyID', function(req, res) {
   var id = req.query['getStudyID'];
   //pass this to a variable to be used by various functions.
   downloadImagesToNodeServer(id);
   zipImageFiles();
   returnTheZipFileBackToUser(id);

   }
```

Then return the zipped file which contains the images back to the user.

```
  function returnTheZipFileToUser(id) {

    var path = require('path');
    var mime = require('mime');
    var file = __dirname + '/public/imagelocation/' + id + '.zip';
    var filename = path.basename(file);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    filestream.pipe(res);
 }
```

The returnTheZipFileToUser is called too early before the images are downloaded and zipped. Therefore I get the image.zip file not found problem as it is triggered way too early before the zipImageFiles() and downloadImagesToNodeServer.

I found a hacky way to implement the setTimeout to wait for the downloads to finish then trigger the returnTheZipFileToUser(id). But this is not a real solution as the timing is different depending on the size of the images and the zip file. 
So I need a surefire way that the images are downloaded completely and zipped file is ready before the returnTheZipFileToUser is called.

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you return the stream from `downloadImageAndSave`, you could then use something like [stream-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-concat) to concat all of the streams into a single stream that you could listen for the finish event:

```
function downloadImages(imageParameters, cb) {

  var streams = imageParameters.map(function (image) {
    var imageUrL = baseURL + "&param1=" + image.imageparam1 + "&param2=" + image.imageparam2 + "&param3=" + image.imageparam3 ;

    var imageparam1 = image.imageparam1;
    return downloadImageAndSave(imageUrL, imageparam1);
  });

  var combinedStream = new StreamConcat(streams);
  combinedStream.on('error', function(error) {
    cb(error);
  });
  combinedStream.on('finish', function() {
    cb();
  });
}

function downloadImageAndSave(imageUrL, imageparam1) {

    console.log("Download function is triggered")
    var fs = require('fs'),
        request = require('request');

    return request
        .get(imageUrL)
        .on('error', function(err) {
            // handle error
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./imagesLocation/' + imageparam1 + '.jpeg'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.
I am not sure where the callback function is defined in this

Comment: Hi pgreen2, I am still struggling with this one.
I have 2 functions that I need to trigger after downloading the images.
1- Zip the images to a folder 
2- Copy zip file to a different location.
I have these functions under combined.stream.on('finish'). It just does not trigger the functions. Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: 'finish' should be called for any stream except if an error occurred.  Are you handling the error event?

Comment: Hi pgreen2, thanks for your message. I just did an update to my code above. It roughly explains what I am trying to achieve. I would appreciate if you could take a look at it . Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an express expert, but my guess is that your problem is less about streams and more about async vs sync code.  The express example you have there indicates to me that it is written in a synchronous manner, but streams are inherently async. I would direct you to google search about express and asynch/callback or pipes patterns. At a high level what needs to happen is `downloadImagesToNodeServer` returns a stream which is piped into `zipImageFiles` which returns a stream which is piped into the express response.  As mentioned before, I'm just not familiar enough with express to say how.

Comment: @pgreen2: His problem is indeed with sync/async, not with express.